# mysql installation with support for this new authentication method (caching_sha2_password)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-20.04

plugin requires new versions of connectors and clients, with support for
this new authentication method (caching_sha2_password). Currently MySQL
8 Connectors and community drivers built with libmysqlclient21 support
this new method. Clients built with older versions of libmysqlclient may
not be able to connect to the new server.

To retain compatibility with older client software, the default
authentication plugin can be set to the legacy value
`(mysql_native_password)`. This should only be done if required third-party
software has not been updated to work with the new authentication
method. The change will be written to the file

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/default-auth-override.cnf
```

After installation, the default can be changed by setting the
default_authentication_plugin server setting.

```
                             <Ok>
```

This result is showing what is the solution?

Comment: You need to frame this as a question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a question.